# iscsiadm initialize target larger than 2TB

Tags: linux, ubuntu, iscsi

## Background

I'm setting up ISCSI on my Linux server at home and I bought a 4 TB WDBlack to use.

At first, I had mounted the HD and created a partition, created the target through Webmin and initiated it on the initiator. The target created it as a 2TB target which I found weird but I initiated it anyway to test and get some practice. It worked but only showed 2TB.

After a while I went back into `fdisk -l` and saw that I created a 2TB partition. Did some research and saw that I needed to set the partition to use a GPT table. I recreated the partition with GPT and it finally read the 4TB (3.7TB). I recreated the target in Webmin and it finally made a 4TB (3.7TB) target!

## Problem

I went to the initiator and logged into it but it still initiated a 2TB volume. I have been researching on how to initiate a target larger than 2TB but I have not found any results. I also briefly skimmed through the `iscsiadm` man page and have not seen anything regarding size of targets.

Is there a limit to what `open-iscsi` can initiate? (2TB). Is there a reason why I can't initiate a volume larger than 2TB even though the target is twice that size? If so, is there a certain workaround?

The command im using to initiate the target is

```
sudo iscsiadm -m node --targetname "iqn.2017-07.co.linuxman.LINUXSRVR:extstorage" --portal "192.168.0.13:3260" --logout
```

Answer (score 0):

Funny as i was writing this i was researching the difference between `block level` and `file level` for targets. As it turns out, `block level` is mainly used for devices where as `file level` acts, in my view, as an "image" so-to-speak so its limited to 2TB. Anyhow, creating the target to `block level` allowed the initiator to mount all 4TB (3.7TB).

Article: http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/the-enterprise-cloud/block-level-storage-vs-file-level-storage-a-comparison/

Hope this helps others in the future!

Comment: Sir, what would be really helpful is putting the parts from the source quoted in your answer in case the link ever goes bad the quoted content is still available here on SU. That would make this a better answer and probably attract more votes as well. You should take a quick stab <::;;::;;::;;{|||||||||}o at it!!!!